# Android Red line under "Selector" when i Make A Drawable Selector

Tags: android

I want to make a selector file in:" @drewable\XML File Android" , But the android studio show to my a red line under "selector" without a suggestions for a solution.

[That what the android studio show to my](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1edL2.png)

I make all of this with the guide of trav :
http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/13239/android-mysql-php-json-part-6-json-parsing-and-android-design/

Answer (score 0):

The "Android XML File" folder inside of your drawable folder isn't allowed. All of your drawable images and XML files need to be in a proper drawable folder. Either in the root drawable or in the appropriate dpi based folder such as drawable-hdpi.

Comment: I dont think that the problem (i tried to move to the drawable folder ), but now i just see that the compiler do not recognize the R file .

Comment: If Android Studio does not accept the R class then that means the project did not compile without an error. Try doing a Build->Rebuild Project. This will perform a clean and then make the project regenerating the R class. If it fails to build look for any errors in the log and post them.